# Finding expectation and variance of poisson random variable.

Tags: probability

Hi I have an unsolved problem that I hope someone are willing to help me with.

A poisson distributed random variable X, where X>0, has  the probabillity to get an outcome equal to 0.6. Determine the expecation and variance of X.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: I know that lambda gives both the variance and the expectation, but can not figure out how to solve for lambda?

Comment: I find the phrasing of the Question confusing.  A Poisson distribution is discrete, so what is meant by "random variable $X$... has the probability to get an outcome equal to $0.6$"?  Are we to assume $0.6$ is the probability of the event $X= 1$?

Comment: Sorry but "A poisson distributed random variable X, where X>0" is absurd since every Poisson random variable X is such that P(X=0) is nonzero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An RV with a Poisson distribution takes values X=0,1,2... so that $$.6 = P(X > 0)=1-P(X=0).$$
If $\lambda $ is the mean of the distribution then $$P(X = 0) = \frac{{{\lambda ^0}{e^{ - \lambda }}}}{{0!}}={e^{ - \lambda }}.$$
Thus $\ \ \ .6 = 1-{e^{ - \lambda }}.$

From this you get the mean, $\lambda $ and, for Poisson the variance is also $\lambda .$

Comment: yeah. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You are using the fact that the parameter of the Poisson random variable is the mean. A better proof would only assume that $\mu$ is a parameter.

Comment: The parameter of the Poisson distribution is the mean. This is clearly stated at  (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution)

Answer (score 0):

If $\mu$ is the parameter of a Poisson random variable $X$, then for all $k \geq 0$, we will have:
$$ \mathbb{P}[X = k] = \frac{\mu^k e^{-\mu}}{k!}. $$

You can then use [this definition of the exponential function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_function#Formal_definition) and [this definition of the mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Univariate_discrete_random_variable.2C_countable_case) to find $\mathbb{E}[X]$.